# Is it possible to get algorithm.eaSimple to return a logbook that includes all stats from run time?

Tags: python, deap

I want to be able to get all my statistics out of the logbook so I can use it for graphical representation. As it stands my logbook only contains the generation numbers and number of evaluations. The algorithm is calculating and outputting avg, std, min, and max, but they do not get returned so I cannot use them. Is there a way I can get these values out of my algorithm?

I have tried looking at the documentation for creating records, but what is there either doesn't make sense to me, or pertain to my situation.

```
def main():
    pop = toolbox.population(n=300)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(1)

    stats_fit = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats_size = tools.Statistics(len)
    mstats = tools.MultiStatistics(fitness=stats_fit, size=stats_size)

    # my hope is that the values calculated by these functions show up in my logbook
    mstats.register("avg", numpy.mean)
    mstats.register("std", numpy.std)
    mstats.register("min", numpy.min)
    mstats.register("max", numpy.max)

    pop, log = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, 0.5, 0.1, 200, stats=mstats,
                                   halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

    print(str(log[0]))  # only outputs generations, number of evaluations
```

my output from this looks like this (note I excluded the output from the algorithm that had to do with the tree's size as I didn't think it was necessary and cluttered the output, but it does output that data)

```
gen nevals  avg     gen max     min     
0   300     1125.92 0   45318.7 83.1079
1   173     1031.65 1   33883.4 83.1079
2   163     779.317 2   1888.68 83.1079
3   149     901.061 3   33606.2 82.4655
4   165     686.407 4   33883.4 81.8855
5   177     962.785 5   33757   81.8855
6   184     1632.86 6   33885.7 81.8855
7   171     1509.72 7   33856.9 81.8855
8   182     984.048 8   33732.6 81.6701
9   177     1534.63 9   34009.9 81.3255
10  159     1277.39 10  33885.7 80.9722 
{'gen': 0, 'nevals': 300}
```

I expect that the final line should include everything else in the log

EDIT:

digging deeper I have found that this may be a bug. The documentation says that it is supposed to be logged when stats are included here https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/algo.html

it reads "It returns the optimized population and a Logbook with the statistics of the evolution. The logbook will contain the generation number, the number of evaluations for each generation and the statistics if a Statistics is given as argument."

I have included statistics but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use multiple statistics, you have to specify the chapter of the logbook you want to access. In your example, the statistics have two chapters: `fitness` and `size`. Therefore, the last line in your example should be

```
print(log.chapters['fitness'][0])
print(log.chapters['size'][0])
```

which will output

```
{'avg': 0.5061951303359752,
 'std': 0.12547520913281693,
 'min': 0.15187521062437034,
 'max': 0.9576681760851814,
 'gen': 0,
 'nevals': 300}
{'avg': 5.0, 'std': 0.0, 'min': 5, 'max': 5, 'gen': 0, 'nevals': 300}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it seemed to be caused by the fact I was using MultiStatistics. I went back to normal Statistics and it worked fine

```
def main():
    pop = toolbox.population(n=300)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(1)

    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", numpy.mean)
    stats.register("std", numpy.std)
    stats.register("min", numpy.min)
    stats.register("max", numpy.max)

    pop, log = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, 0.5, 0.1, 40, stats,
                                   halloffame=hof, verbose=True)
    print(str(log[0]))
```